# Select columns from data frame using 1, 0 list , pandas

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns

I have a list of 1,0 where each element is corresponding to an index of a column on a data frame, for example:
df.columns = ['a','b','c']
binary_list = [0,1,0]

based on that I want to select only b column from the data frame as on my binary list it has 1 only corresponds to b

is there a way to perform that in pandas?

P.S this is my first time posting on stackoverflow, apologies if I am not following a specific styling

Answer (score 0):

If the binary list is aligned with the columns, you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

binary_list = [0,1,0]

df.loc[:, map(bool, binary_list)]
```

Output:

```
   b
0  2
```